# Different user login (same 'pi' username) depending on method

Tags: python, login, user

I'm just using putty and SSH'ing into a Raspberry Pi

1. If I log in using the hostname "pi@raspberrypi" + password 
   then I get one filesystem/folders.
2. If I determine the Pi IP address using ifconfig,then
3. login using putty and IP address i.e. pi@ 192.168.43.237 I get a completely different file system
4. When I log onto the Pi I can see 2x pi users accounts active (which is what I expect)

How can this be? The python project scripts/files that I want to use are only available on one of the above

Comment: Please post the output of pwd and ls -la for both logins. Can you explain what you mean by you "see 2x pi user accounts"? How are you determining this? did you attempt to create a second pi user?